# Why does GetHostAddresses("www.google.com") only return one IPAddress?

Tags: c#, dns

```
IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.google.com");
```

I think it should return multiple ip but it only return one, how can I get full ip address correspond www.google.com ...

Comment: Blame your DNS server. Or try to use some other one - like Google's 8.8.8.8.